# uiImageView showing borders between images in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

We have a row of 139x127 images that are displaying with borders in our collection view cell.  we tried UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill (and Fit) but it is still showing the borders.

The code is below:
// uicollectionviewcell

```
(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfilePhotoCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    return self;

}
return self;
}

 // uicollectionview/viewcontroller
// 1
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// 2
CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(100, 66);
return retval;
}

  // 3
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
 (UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is a screenshot: ! http://m.mirror.co/collection.png

Comment: what you want... image with border or without border

Comment: images without spacing/padding between them

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: no, i tried that earlier but did not work. What's weird is that changing that increasing the top, bottom, left, and right values DID increase the spacing between them, even if I used negative values, but still couldn't remove the spacing between images.

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: no that didn't work either, as stated in my original post.

Comment: you are setting its frame somewhere else

Comment: can you please describe form what context the source code above is taken? -initWithFrame: suggest it's your uicollectionviewcell subclass, but the other two methods seem like belonging to a uicollectionviewdelegate ...

Comment: Ahti, that's correct.  The first part of the code is the uicollectionviewcell subclass.  The bottom two methods are in main view controller. Mark asked about the collectionViewLayout property of the UICollectionView.

Comment: adjust the value in sizeForItemAtIndexPath to have 320.0/3.0 as width

Comment: Sorry ahti, ios newbie here, not sure I follow.  Where do I define that?

Comment: where are you setting frame

Answer (score 0):

What is going on with your collectionViewLayout property of the UICollectionView? I am guessing that the UICollectionView is padding the cells it is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes i have found it priceless to use `LLDB` by pausing the app and running...

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

This will give you the pointers to each view object.  Then i will run...

```
po [0xabcd123 constraints]
```

...to see if any auto constraints were added at runtime you didn't know about.  Also, you can get the frame size of your cell and your view and see if they match.  You may need to programmatically delete auto constraints and apply new constraints pinning your view to your cell.  I ran into some of this while making a view cell "flip" from view to view.

Don't forget to turn off the auto constraints in your init or IB...

```
[self.imageview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Good luck!